# How To Cancel Timer or Signal Tab When It's Lost Focus (React Native App)

Tags: react-native

I am building an app with React Native that has tabbed interface, implemented with `createBottomTabNavigator()` (@react-navigation/bottom-tabs). One of the tabs can have a looping behavior at the user's discretion: a sound is played, there's pause, and the next sound in the list is played. The loop basically has 3 states: playing, sleeping and fetching the next sound.

If the tab is active and the user has turned on the looping, when they navigate away, I don't have a way to stop the loop gracefully. I resorted to putting the sound object in a shared context and the bottom tab navigator stops the sound when the active tab switches, `soundObject.stopAsync()` but if the code's in the sleeping state when it completes, it has no idea that it no longer has focus and it fetches the the next sound and continues in the loop.

There must be a cleaner way to either stop the timer or alert the loop code that it shouldn't proceed when the timer completes, but I'm not seeing what it is. Happy to paste as much code as you want, but I think my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the hooks provided by the `react-navigation` library.

You can use the `useIsFocused` hook, which returns a boolean indicating whether or not the screen is focused, which you could access somewhere in your loop to decide whether or not it should proceed.

Alternatively there is the `useFocusEffect` which could also work for your use case:

> React Navigation provides a hook that runs an effect when the screen comes into focus and cleans it up when it goes out of focus. This is useful for cases such as adding event listeners, for fetching data with an API call when a screen becomes focused, or any other action that needs to happen once the screen comes into view.

> This is particularly handy when we are trying to stop something when the page is unfocused, like stopping a video or audio file from playing, or stopping the tracking of a user's location.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/

Comment: What I missed is the relevance of useIsFocused(). The documentation mentioned the "screen" having focus and I was thinking app losing focus. D'oh. Thank you!!